# R - how to expand timestamps to each id in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I want to expand a df with time column.

Here I have 2 df:

```
book1 <- data.frame(
  id = c('A1', 'A2', 'A3')
)
book2 <- data.frame(
  year = c('2000', '2010', '2020')  
)

> book1
  id
1 A1
2 A2
3 A3

> book2
  year
1 2000
2 2010
3 2020
```

What I expect is

```
  id year
1 A1 2000
2 A1 2010
3 A1 2020
4 A2 2000
5 A2 2010
6 A2 2020
7 A3 2000
8 A3 2010
9 A3 2020
```

Could anyone help me to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge()`.  For desired ordering of the result, we use `book2` as the first argument and then `rev`erse the column order of the result.

```
rev(merge(book2, book1))
#   id year
# 1 A1 2000
# 2 A1 2010
# 3 A1 2020
# 4 A2 2000
# 5 A2 2010
# 6 A2 2020
# 7 A3 2000
# 8 A3 2010
# 9 A3 2020
```

Answer (score 1):

Use expand.grid:

```
df <- expand.grid(book1$id, book2$year)
df
```